# C# convert 1D array to 2D

Tags: c#, linq

I find myself converting 1D byte and single arrays to 2D by doing the following. I suspect it is probably as fast as other methods, but perhaps there is a cleaner simpler paradigm? (Linq?)

```
    private static byte[,] byte2D(byte[] input, int height, int width)
    {
        byte[,] output = new byte[height, width];
        for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
            {
                output[i, j] = input[i * width + j];
            }
        }
        return output;
    }

    private static Single[,] single2D(byte[] input, int height, int width)
    {
        Single[,] output = new Single[height, width];
        for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
            {
                output[i, j] = (Single)input[i * width + j];
            }
        }
        return output;
    }
```

Comment: Your second method, is the type of `input` supposed to be `byte[]`?

Comment: Can you provide sample input/output for one of those functions?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This doesn't help with making the code inside the methods cleaner, but I noticed that you have 2 basically identical methods that differ only in their types.  I suggest using [generics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcad0zb.aspx).

This would let you define your method only once.  Using the [`where`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx) keyword, you can even limit the kind of types you allow your method to work on.

```
private static T[,] Make2DArray<T>(T[] input, int height, int width)
{
    T[,] output = new T[height, width];
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            output[i, j] = input[i * width + j];
        }
    }
    return output;
}
```

You would call this method like this

```
int[] a;  //or any other array.
var twoDArray = Make2DArray(a, height, width);
```

Comment: Buffer.BlockCopy() is faster and simpler. Been around since Framework 1.1

Comment: @dynamichael only works though if your type actually has a constant size in bytes .. wouldn't work e.g. for `string`

Answer (score 7):

`Buffer.BlockCopy(input, 0, output, 0, input.Length);` is faster, but fastest is to not copy the array at all.

If you don't really need a separate 2D array, you can just access your 1D array like a 2D array trough a function, property, or custom type. For example:

```
class D2<T> {
    T[] input;
    int lenght0;
    public d2(T[] input, int lenght0) {
        this.input = input;
        this.lenght0 = lenght0;
    }
    public T this[int index0, int index1] {
        get { return input[index0 * this.lenght0 + index1]; }
        set { input[index0 * this.lenght0 + index1] = value; }
    }
}

...

byte[] input = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
var output = new D2<byte>(input, 2);
output[1, 1] = 0;  // now input is { 1, 2, 3, 0 };
```

Also, in .NET access to multidimensional arrays is a bit slower than access to jagged arrays

Comment: Buffer.BlockCopy seems only to work for arrays based on primitive types, not e.g. object[].

Answer (score 2):

Generic function:

```
private static b[,] to2D<a, b>(a source, valueAt: Func<a, int, b>, int height, int width)
{
    var result = new b[height, width];
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            result[i, j] = valueAt(source, i * width + j);
        }
    }
    return result;
}

var bytes = to2D<byte[], byte>([], (bytes, at) => bytes[at], 10, 20);
```

Answer (score 2):

I know I am late to the party, but if you want to access a 1d array, list, etc. like it were an n-dimensional array (without copying) you can use https://github.com/henon/SliceAndDice to do so without copying.

```
// create a 2D array of bytes from a byte[]
var a = new ArraySlice<byte>( new byte[100], new Shape(10,10));
// now access with 2d coordinates
a[7,9]=(byte)56;
```

Of course, everyone can do it for simple 2d, 3d, ... nd volumes easily. But this lib also allows to do slicing of n-dimensional arrays without copying.